# KnockoutJs: Getting value from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm having hard time getting the selected value of dropdown list using Knockout JS

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lincx/2BEwR/1/)

HTML

```
     <select id="l" data-bind="options: locations, value=selectedLocation"></select>
     <select id="j" data-bind="options: jobTypes, value=selectedJobType"></select>
     <button data-bind="click: myFunction"> Display </button>
```

Script

```
       var viewModel = {
            locations: ko.observableArray(['All Locations', 'Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Brisbane', 'Darwin', 'Perth', 'Adelaide']),
            selectedLocation: ko.observable(),

            jobTypes: ko.observableArray(['All Vacancies', 'Administration', 'Engineering', 'Legal', 'Sales', 'Accounting']),
            selectedJobType: ko.observable(),

            myFunction: function() {
                alert(selectedJobType + ' ' +selectedLocation );
            }
        };
        // ... then later ...
        //viewModel.availableCountries.push('China');
        // Adds another option
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be

```
value:selectedLocation
```

and:

```
value:selectedJobType
```

in you bindings. Bindings use the same syntax as an object literal.

Also, in your alert, you need `viewModel.selectedJobType()`, because (a) it's a property of `viewModel` not of global and (b) it's an observable so you need to call it to get the value. Same for `selectedLocation`.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BEwR/2/)